# How can I delete a property from object returned by mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am querying users collection and I don't want to send back password. My main point is that if I can perform javascript operations on mongodb objects or not. Here is my code:

```
router.get("/:userId", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.userId);
    delete user.password;
    if (user.parent !== undefined) {
      const referrer = await User.findOne({ _id: user.parent });
      return res.json({ user, referrer });
    }
    res.json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json(error);
  }
});
```

I am getting this output

```
{
    "is_deleted": false,
    "packages": [],
    "_id": "5ed102f3fefa080404db01df",
    "name": "parent",
    "email": "parent@parent.com",
    "gender": "m",
    "password": "$2b$10$HTGaoy.AVmoG/A0c/vkikO0NnEBte7f2tvwt2FQE94bZlNiYTeX8i",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I tried to perform filter on a list of mongodb objects and that failed too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can destructure the object returned from the query

```
const {password, ...restProps } = await User.findById(req.params.userId);
const user = restProps;
```

You can also configure your `User` model so that `password` field is excluded by default from query result.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    password: {
       ...
       select: false
    }
});
```

if you don't want to exclude a field by default, you can call `select` function and specify the properties you don't want to include in the query results.

```
const user = await User.findById(req.params.userId).select('-password');
```

for more info on this, see [SchemaType.prototype.select()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-select)

Comment: Does that mean I cannot perform javascript operations on these objects returned by the database?

Comment: you can. destructuring is a javascript feature.

Comment: I read select: false solution somewhere in the docs perhaps but I need password when logging in the user.

Comment: Thank you so much. The last solution is what I really needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `findeOne` with the projection on the end:

```
const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.params.userId },{ password: 0 });
```

You can exclude more fields with setting the value to `0`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign undefined to that property to ignore when send as JSON to client.
Like:

```
  const user = await User.findById(id);
  user.password = undefined;
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    user,
  });
```